# Sorting alphanumeric character according to requirement

Tags: database, oracle

I have data in database as `[AD AC AB AA H7 H2 H4 H3 H8 H6 H5 H9 H1 HL HJ HH HG HF 1S 1B 1G 1A]` I need to display it as `[AD AC AB AA HL HJ HH HG HF H9 H8 H6 H7 H5 H4 H3 H2 H1 1S 1G 1B 1A]`. Can you please help me.

Till now i have tried this

```
select distinct Col1
from    Table1
order by regexp_substr(Col1  , '^[[:alpha:]]') , 
regexp_substr(Col1  , '[[:alpha:]]', 1,2) desc,
regexp_substr(Col1  , '^\d*'),
regexp_substr(regexp_substr(Col1  , '_[[:alpha:]]*') ,'[[:alpha:]]+') desc;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what are the requirements here. Can you provide an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select distinct col1  
from table_name
order by 
regexp_substr(Col1 , '^[[:alpha:]]') ,
SUBSTR(Col1, 2, 1) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more info or describe your requirement more for additional cases.

However from the data you have posted already, here is a query that can do it.

```
WITH mydat
     AS (SELECT 'AD' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'AC' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'AB' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'AA' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'H7' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'H2' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'H4' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'H3' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'H8' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'H6' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'H5' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'H9' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'H1' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'HL' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'HJ' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'HH' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'HG' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'HF' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '1S' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '1B' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '1G' AS Col1 FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '1A' AS Col1 FROM DUAL)
  SELECT Col1,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR (Col1, '^[[:alpha:]]') first_char_else_null,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR (Col1, '^[[:digit:]]') first_num_else_null,
         SUBSTR (Col1, 2, 1) second_char,
         ASCII (SUBSTR (Col1, 2, 1)) ascii_second_char
    FROM mydat
ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (Col1, '^[[:alpha:]]') NULLS LAST,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR (Col1, '^[[:digit:]]') NULLS FIRST,
         ASCII (SUBSTR (Col1, 2, 1)) DESC;
```

Comment: Sir i need to use dynamic statement. Thanks for your response, I got the solution.